# How to merge two csv files based on one matching column in unix. The position of column is different in both file

Tags: awk

I want to merge file2.csv with file1.csv based on matching column values. col1 of files 2 needs to be matched with col4 of file one. if it matches then merge the file2.csv with file1.csv.

file2.csv

```
1111_2222_2222,3333
1112_2223_2224,3333
```

File1.csv

```
d20200317,v0000,7777,2001_0218_AAAA,111
d20200318,v0000,7777,0102_5913_AAA,111
```

I tried below awk command but it is not working:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;next}{print $0"," a[$1];}' File1.csv file2.csv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Why OP's attempt didn't work:*** By default `awk` uses field separator as space so we need to set `FS` value to `=` since field separator in csv files is `,`.

Considering that you want to merge files and add column from Input_file1.csv to Input_file2.csv in its last position.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} $4 in a{print $0,a[$4]}'  file1.csv  file2.csv
```

Output will be as follows.

d20200317,v22221,7395,2001_0218_AAAA,111
d20200318,v22221,7395,0102_5913_AAA,111

Comment: Thanks A lot Ravindra! This command is working almost fine for me requirement. But I See that I am missing some records from file2 in the results. But Command is fine for me as per my requirements. Thanks Again! :)

Comment: Hi Ravindra, I have one more question. in my output file I want to sum up the value of 5th column and want to generate only one records if 1st four columns are same. my awk command is as below which I prepared by modifying your based on output I need.                                                                                                                           awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} $4 in a{print $1,$2,$3,a[$4],$5}' .

Comment: @Rachna03, Yes. Thank you. Request you to open a new thread and ping me link here. Please do add your efforts which you have mentioned in comments in that post too, because people encourage that in forums, let me know link once you open new one.

Comment: Hi Sorry, I forgot to update you. I prepared the query on my new request by some hit and trail that is why did not raise new request. :)

Comment: @Rachna03, Sorry Rachn I didn't get it, you want to open a new question you are saying?